# Change color and add legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I'm trying to plot some data ("DAPC2") with two variables linked to coordinates in ggplot2. The data looks like this:

```
         LD1        LD2      Locality   Ecoregion
CA2   0.9524254  -15.906715  Caldera    Central_Chile
CO4   11.4640606  3.644242   Cocholgue  Araucanian
HU2  -17.3216357  10.577911  Huinay     Chiloense
HU4  -17.9015095  10.813084  Huinay     Chiloense
LH1   2.5713149  -17.984544  Herradura  Central_Chile
```

And my code so far is something like this:

```
myPlot <- ggplot(DAPC2, aes(x=DAPC2$LD1, y=DAPC2$LD2))
myPlot + theme_bw() + theme(panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), axis.line=element_line(colour="black")) + geom_point(alpha=0.3, col=as.integer(DAPC2$popnames.Locality), pch=as.integer(DAPC2$popnames.Ecoregion)+14, cex=6)
```

On one hand, I 'm trying to change the color palette, however I could not do it given the integer vector. Also, I'm trying to include a legend that show both variables (i.e. Locality and Ecoregion). Any advice?

Comment: No need to include `DAPC2$` inside the `aes` of `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add colour/shapes to points in ggplot, you want to add colour and shape aesthetics.

Try

`ggplot(DAPC2, aes(x=DAPC2$LD1, y=DAPC2$LD2, colour=Locality, shaoe=Ecoregion))`

and remove all instances if Ecoregion and Locality from the rest of your code. This will also add a legend for both colour and shape.

Answer (score 1):

For the legend part, you could add an extension for the `aes` section.

If you want to have a legend for:

```
myPlot <- ggplot(DAPC2, aes(x=DAPC2$LD1, y=DAPC2$LD2))
```

Change to:

```
myPlot <- ggplot(DAPC2, aes(x=DAPC2$LD1, y=DAPC2$LD2, fill = DAPC2$Locality))
```

If you want both, you could do facet_wrap which will have a legend along with different plots for each Ecoregion.

```
myPlot <- ggplot(DAPC2, aes(x=DAPC2$LD1, y=DAPC2$LD2, fill = DAPC2$Locality), facet_wrap(~DAPC2$Ecoregion))
```